# issue with data sample

Tags: python, dataset, data, visualization, encoding

```
Cell In[24], line 5
      2 from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as sfs
      3 #from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
      4 #from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
----> 5 X_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split('iv','dv', test_size=0.25, stratify = dv)
      7 logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
      8 #logreg.fit(X_train, y_train['binary_num'])
```

Answer (score 1):

[As you can see in the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), the data provided to `train_test_split` need to be arrays of data (e.g. numpy arrays or pandas dataframe), not strings. If your data is stored in the `iv` and `dv` variables, the correct way to call the function would be as follows:

```
X_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(iv, dv, test_size=0.25, stratify = dv)
```